Why is this assignment not visible to [ (test command)?
I was reading about shell grammar in the manual and came across the following

Simple Commands
A simple command is a sequence of optional variable assignments followed by blank-separated words  and  redirections, and terminated by a control operator.

So I decided to test this with the following script:
#!/usr/bin/bash
if myVar=hello [ "$myVar" ]; then echo "$myVar"; else echo fail "$myVar"; fi

$ ./test.sh 
fail

I fail to see why this fails, if my understanding of the manual is correct this should work. When trying this script on ShellCheck I get the following warning:

SC2097 (warning): This assignment is only seen by the forked process.

And the explanation goes:

In name=World cmd "$name", name=World is passed in as part of the environment to cmd (i.e., in the envp parameter to execve(2)). This means that cmd and its children will see the parameter, but no other processes will.

Where is this behavior documented in the manual? Nowhere does it say that inline assignments (i just made that term up) are local to the command they are declared. Furthermore, this doesnt explain why the script fails. By this logic, [ should have access to myVar, execute the then block and the script should print nothing.
What am I missing?

Maybe you should have initialized variable myVar before running this script?
$ myVar='hello'
$ if myVar=hello [ "$myVar" ]; then echo "$myVar"; else echo fail "$myVar"; fi
hello

Keep reading the explanation: "However, "$name" is not expanded by cmd. "$name" is expanded by the shell before cmd is ever executed, and thus it will not use the new value."

Possible duplicate: Prefixing variable assignment doesn't work with echo (This is linked from the ShellCheck page.) If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question to make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question don't answer your question.

@macosmi What does that have to do with the question?

My bad, it's not a duplicate, but it does cover your additional confusion: "[ should have access to myVar". No, because [ isn't what's evaluating (expanding) "$myVar"; the shell does that.

@wjandrea im a moron lol.

Shellcheck's warning is a little misleading; [ doesn't necessarily fork a new process (it's a shell-builtin here), but the command still has its own environment for the purposes of evaluating it.

You just have to terminate assignement before testing. add a semicolon: if myVar=hello ; [ "$myVar" ]; then

The section you're reading only explains the syntax, not the semantics.  For the latter, see the section "Simple Command Expansion" in the bash manual.

When a simple command is executed, the shell performs the following
expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to right, in the
following order.

The words that the parser has marked as variable assignments (those preceding the command name) and redirections are saved for
later processing.
The words that are not variable assignments or redirections are expanded (see Shell Expansions). If any words remain after expansion,
the first word is taken to be the name of the command and the
remaining words are the arguments.
Redirections are performed as described above (see Redirections).
The text after the ‘=’ in each variable assignment undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable.

If no command name results, the variable assignments affect the
current shell environment. In the case of such a command (one that
consists only of assignment statements and redirections), assignment
statements are performed before redirections. Otherwise, the variables
are added to the environment of the executed command and do not affect
the current shell environment. If any of the assignments attempts to
assign a value to a readonly variable, an error occurs, and the
command exits with a non-zero status.

So first, note that expansions, which includes substituting $myVar with the value of myVar, are done (step 2) before the assignment is performed (step 4).  Thus, $myVar is replaced with the previous value of myVar, which is empty.
Moreover, as I've highlighted in bold, even when the assignment is performed, it is only in the environment of the executed command, namely [.  So it will not be visible to any other commands, such as those in the then or else clauses.  This is a feature, as it provides a way to run a single command with a different value for a particular variable, without having to manually save and restore the variable's value around the command.
